# GPS tracker server side script

Tags: php, sockets, gps

I have a GPS Tracking unit that I want to connect to my server. I am using PHP SocketServer.class.php. Now my problem is the data I receive from the Tracking is

> ))±

But that is wrong. Here is a [link](http://www.armand.co.za/Amwell/) to download the Standard Protocol for the Unit. Could someone please show me where my fault could be...

index.php

```
error_reporting(0);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush();

require_once("SocketServer.class.php"); // Include the File
$server = new SocketServer("154.0.160.80",5522); // Create a Server binding to the given ip address and listen to port 31337 for connections
$server->max_clients = 10; // Allow no more than 10 people to connect at a time
$server->hook("CONNECT","handle_connect"); // Run handle_connect every time someone connects
$server->hook("INPUT","handle_input"); // Run handle_input whenever text is sent to the server
$server->infinite_loop(); // Run Server Code Until Process is terminated.


function handle_connect(&$server,&$client,$input)
{
    SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"String? ","");
}
function handle_input(&$server,&$client,$input)
{

}
```

SocketServer.class.php

```
/*! @class      SocketServer
    @author     Navarr Barnier
    @abstract   A Framework for creating a multi-client server using the PHP language.
 */
class SocketServer
{
    /*! @var        config
        @abstract   Array - an array of configuration information used by the server.
     */
    protected $config;

    /*! @var        hooks
        @abstract   Array - a dictionary of hooks and the callbacks attached to them.
     */
    protected $hooks;

    /*! @var        master_socket
        @abstract   resource - The master socket used by the server.
     */
    protected $master_socket;

    /*! @var        max_clients
        @abstract   unsigned int - The maximum number of clients allowed to connect.
     */
    public $max_clients = 10;

    /*! @var        max_read
        @abstract   unsigned int - The maximum number of bytes to read from a socket at a single time.
     */
    public $max_read = 1024;

    /*! @var        clients
        @abstract   Array - an array of connected clients.
     */
    public $clients;

    /*! @function   __construct
        @abstract   Creates the socket and starts listening to it.
        @param      string  - IP Address to bind to, NULL for default.
        @param      int - Port to bind to
        @result     void
     */
    public function __construct($bind_ip,$port)
    {
        set_time_limit(0);
        $this->hooks = array();

        $this->config["ip"] = $bind_ip;
        $this->config["port"] = $port;

        $this->master_socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        socket_bind($this->master_socket,$this->config["ip"],$this->config["port"]) or die("Issue Binding");
        socket_getsockname($this->master_socket,$bind_ip,$port);
        socket_listen($this->master_socket);
        SocketServer::debug("Listenting for connections on {$bind_ip}:{$port}");
    }

    /*! @function   hook
        @abstract   Adds a function to be called whenever a certain action happens.  Can be extended in your implementation.
        @param      string  - Command
        @param      callback- Function to Call.
        @see        unhook
        @see        trigger_hooks
        @result     void
     */
    public function hook($command,$function)
    {
        $command = strtoupper($command);
        if(!isset($this->hooks[$command])) { $this->hooks[$command] = array(); }
        $k = array_search($function,$this->hooks[$command]);
        if($k === FALSE)
        {
            $this->hooks[$command][] = $function;
        }
    }

    /*! @function   unhook
        @abstract   Deletes a function from the call list for a certain action.  Can be extended in your implementation.
        @param      string  - Command
        @param      callback- Function to Delete from Call List
        @see        hook
        @see        trigger_hooks
        @result     void
     */
    public function unhook($command = NULL,$function)
    {
        $command = strtoupper($command);
        if($command !== NULL)
        {
            $k = array_search($function,$this->hooks[$command]);
            if($k !== FALSE)
            {
                unset($this->hooks[$command][$k]);
            }
        } else {
            $k = array_search($this->user_funcs,$function);
            if($k !== FALSE)
            {
                unset($this->user_funcs[$k]);
            }
        }
    }

    /*! @function   loop_once
        @abstract   Runs the class's actions once.
        @discussion Should only be used if you want to run additional checks during server operation.  Otherwise, use infinite_loop()
        @param      void
        @see        infinite_loop
        @result     bool    - True
    */
    public function loop_once()
    {
        // Setup Clients Listen Socket For Reading
        $read[0] = $this->master_socket;
        for($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients; $i++)
        {
            if(isset($this->clients[$i]))
            {
                $read[$i + 1] = $this->clients[$i]->socket;
            }
        }

        // Set up a blocking call to socket_select
        if(socket_select($read,$write = NULL, $except = NULL, $tv_sec = 5) < 1)
        {
        //  SocketServer::debug("Problem blocking socket_select?");
            return true;
        }

        // Handle new Connections
        if(in_array($this->master_socket, $read))
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients; $i++)
            {
                if(empty($this->clients[$i]))
                {
                    $temp_sock = $this->master_socket;
                    $this->clients[$i] = new SocketServerClient($this->master_socket,$i);
                    $this->trigger_hooks("CONNECT",$this->clients[$i],"");
                    break;
                }
                elseif($i == ($this->max_clients-1))
                {
                    SocketServer::debug("Too many clients... :( ");
                }
            }

        }

        // Handle Input
        for($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients; $i++) // for each client
        {
            if(isset($this->clients[$i]))
            {
                if(in_array($this->clients[$i]->socket, $read))
                {
                    $input = socket_read($this->clients[$i]->socket, $this->max_read);
                    if($input == null)
                    {
                        $this->disconnect($i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SocketServer::debug("{$i}@{$this->clients[$i]->ip} --> {$input}");
                        $this->trigger_hooks("INPUT",$this->clients[$i],$input);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /*! @function   disconnect
        @abstract   Disconnects a client from the server.
        @param      int - Index of the client to disconnect.
        @param      string  - Message to send to the hooks
        @result     void
    */
    public function disconnect($client_index,$message = "")
    {
        $i = $client_index;
        SocketServer::debug("Client {$i} from {$this->clients[$i]->ip} Disconnecting");
        $this->trigger_hooks("DISCONNECT",$this->clients[$i],$message);
        $this->clients[$i]->destroy();
        unset($this->clients[$i]);          
    }

    /*! @function   trigger_hooks
        @abstract   Triggers Hooks for a certain command.
        @param      string  - Command who's hooks you want to trigger.
        @param      object  - The client who activated this command.
        @param      string  - The input from the client, or a message to be sent to the hooks.
        @result     void
    */
    public function trigger_hooks($command,&$client,$input)
    {
        if(isset($this->hooks[$command]))
        {
            foreach($this->hooks[$command] as $function)
            {
                //SocketServer::debug("Triggering Hook '{$function}' for '{$command}'");
                $continue = call_user_func($function,$this,$client,$input);
                if($continue === FALSE) { break; }
            }
        }
    }

    /*! @function   infinite_loop
        @abstract   Runs the server code until the server is shut down.
        @see        loop_once
        @param      void
        @result     void
    */
    public function infinite_loop()
    {
        $test = true;
        do
        {
            $test = $this->loop_once();
        }
        while($test);
    }

    /*! @function   debug
        @static
        @abstract   Outputs Text directly.
        @discussion Yeah, should probably make a way to turn this off.
        @param      string  - Text to Output
        @result     void
    */
    public static function debug($text)
    {
        echo("{$text}\r\n");
    }

    /*! @function   socket_write_smart
        @static
        @abstract   Writes data to the socket, including the length of the data, and ends it with a CRLF unless specified.
        @discussion It is perfectly valid for socket_write_smart to return zero which means no bytes have been written. Be sure to use the === operator to check for FALSE in case of an error. 
        @param      resource- Socket Instance
        @param      string  - Data to write to the socket.
        @param      string  - Data to end the line with.  Specify a "" if you don't want a line end sent.
        @result     mixed   - Returns the number of bytes successfully written to the socket or FALSE on failure. The error code can be retrieved with socket_last_error(). This code may be passed to socket_strerror() to get a textual explanation of the error.
    */
    public static function socket_write_smart(&$sock,$string,$crlf = "\r\n")
    {
        SocketServer::debug("<-- {$string}");
        if($crlf) { $string = "{$string}{$crlf}"; }
        return socket_write($sock,$string,strlen($string));
    }

    /*! @function   __get
        @abstract   Magic Method used for allowing the reading of protected variables.
        @discussion You never need to use this method, simply calling $server->variable works because of this method's existence.
        @param      string  - Variable to retrieve
        @result     mixed   - Returns the reference to the variable called.
    */
    function &__get($name)
    {
        return $this->{$name};
    }
}

/*! @class      SocketServerClient
    @author     Navarr Barnier
    @abstract   A Client Instance for use with SocketServer
 */
class SocketServerClient
{
    /*! @var        socket
        @abstract   resource - The client's socket resource, for sending and receiving data with.
     */
    protected $socket;

    /*! @var        ip
        @abstract   string - The client's IP address, as seen by the server.
     */
    protected $ip;

    /*! @var        hostname
        @abstract   string - The client's hostname, as seen by the server.
        @discussion This variable is only set after calling lookup_hostname, as hostname lookups can take up a decent amount of time.
        @see        lookup_hostname
     */
    protected $hostname;

    /*! @var        server_clients_index
        @abstract   int - The index of this client in the SocketServer's client array.
     */
    protected $server_clients_index;

    /*! @function   __construct
        @param      resource- The resource of the socket the client is connecting by, generally the master socket.
        @param      int - The Index in the Server's client array.
        @result     void
     */
    public function __construct(&$socket,$i)
    {
        $this->server_clients_index = $i;
        $this->socket = socket_accept($socket) or die("Failed to Accept");
        SocketServer::debug("New Client Connected");
        socket_getpeername($this->socket,$ip);
        $this->ip = $ip;
    }

    /*! @function   lookup_hostname
        @abstract   Searches for the user's hostname and stores the result to hostname.
        @see        hostname
        @param      void
        @result     string  - The hostname on success or the IP address on failure.
     */
    public function lookup_hostname()
    {
        $this->hostname = gethostbyaddr($this->ip);
        return $this->hostname;
    }

    /*! @function   destroy
        @abstract   Closes the socket.  Thats pretty much it.
        @param      void
        @result     void
     */
    public function destroy()
    {
        socket_close($this->socket);
    }

    function &__get($name)
    {
        return $this->{$name};
    }

    function __isset($name)
    {
        return isset($this->{$name});
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code you retrieve the data with.

Comment: Would I be able to do the required task in PHP or must I make use of another language? I can update the unit to send to someone that will be able to help me so they can recreate my problem

Comment: What do you want to achieve by sending `'String? '` while the docuemntation clearly states that _every_ command should start with two closing parentheses `))`? It’s definitely possible to achieve the goal, but it’s not a five-minites golf.

Comment: The code above, would it be easier to use or write my own custom code? Would you be able to assist me with this? Even if I have to pay you to assist me?